# EASYProcess eCommerce website is timing out and no logs are being created

Tags: jdedwards

We have an eCommerce website running on EASYProcess. We are going to Shopping cart page and it is unresponsive. Page will take forever to load and then will time out. Every pages after that will time out. When we look at the app server, EASYProcess service running on app server will max on memory, the minute we hit shopping cart page. So it seems something in the shopping cart page causing this but there is no log in the application logs for EASYProcess to check.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without any specifics or context, this question is very broad and unclear, and will likely be closed as off-topic, as written. Please edit to include specific details. That said: maybe this question is better suited for the vendor's specific support forum? As written, t seems like an installation/setup issue and not a programming question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If website is hanging while showing a page, do following steps to troubleshoot:

1. Restart EASYProcess Enterprise Server and make sure website is up and responding to other pages.

   2. Set log level to DEBUG.
   3. Load the page which is throwing error.
   4. Then go to toolset/logfiles folder. Locate latest log file and then look for your request.
   5. You should be able to trace every webpart, data source, process call in there. Looks for the call that has no end trace and that is your culprit.